# SQL Query validation on 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying run a query to fetch the following result from the following tables,

**BaseVehicle Table**

```
BaseVehicleId   DeleteDate

1   NULL
2   NULL
3   NULL
4   NULL
```

**Vehicle Table**

```
VehicleId   BaseVehicleId   DeleteDate

1   1   NULL
2   1   NULL
3   2   08-01-2017
4   3   NULL
5   3   08-01-2017
6   3   NULL
7   1   NULL
8   2   08-01-2017
```

**Result Table**

```
BaseVehicleId

2
4
```

Here DeleteDate would be null, if the record is active.

There is a one to many mapping between BaseVehicle (one) -> Vehicle (many)

I need query to fetch the records where base vehicle Ids are not mapped with Vehicle table and also when all the vehicles that are associated with Base vehicle where DeleteDate is not null. Please let me know how do i achieve this.

I need to fetchthe base vehicle Id's only of all the associated VehicleId's deleteDate is not null (like for BaseVehicleId=2 in Vehicle Table and i should not be reading the value for BaseVehicleId=3 in my result set)

[image]

Comment: So you want BaseVehicleIds of unmapped BaseVehicles to Vechicle table AND mapped BaseVehicleIds with Delete Date not null in Vehicle table???

Comment: @Sujith Yes, Thanks for replying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you should think the opposite way.

First of all we have to query all records from `Vehicle` table which don't have `DeleteDate` field set. Those records and `BaseVehicleId` connected with them we should exclude. It means that we will get only `BaseVehicleId` which don't exist in `Vehicle` table or all records for those ids have `DeleteDate` set.

```
SELECT BaseVehicleId
FROM BaseVehicle
WHERE BaseVehicleId NOT IN (SELECT BaseVehicleId FROM Vehicle WHERE DeleteDate IS NULL)
```

Comment: Yup.. +1 . I have misunderstood a part of the question.

Comment: Thank you Pawel :) It worked perfect