# SQL Query with join to check 2 conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

Master table:

```
MasterID | PartID  
1          1  
2          3  
3          5
```

Part table:

```
PartID | PartName | DeleteDate  
1        Part1      NULL  
2        Part2      NULL  
4        Part4      NULL  
5        Part5      08-04-2017
```

Result table:

```
MasterID | PartID  
2          3  
3          5
```

These two tables are present in two different database and  i need to validate with a SQL query to fetch the record if Master table has PartID that are not in Part table and Master table has any PartID that are deleted in Part table (i.e. DeleteDate IS NOT NULL)

I'm trying with a below query,

```
Select 
    * 
FROM DBNAME.DBO.Master 
Where PartID in (
    Select 
        PartID 
     from Part) 
and PartID not in (
    Select 
        PartID 
    from Part 
    where DeleteDate is NOT NULL)
```

Please let me know is there a better way to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Query validation on 2 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45433427/sql-query-validation-on-2-tables)

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your query to:

```
Select m.* 
from DBNAME.DBO.Master m
where m.PartID not in (Select p.PartID from Part p where p.DeleteDate is NOT NULL);
```

You seem to want rows that are not "not deleted", regardless of whether or not they are in the table.

Comment: No, I have updated my query... I need Only those PartID in Master table that are in Part table and not in those from Part table that are deleted

Answer (score 0):

you dont need the second condition at all.

```
Select * DBNAME.DBO.Master Where PartID not in (Select PartID from Part)
```

that covers `PartID not in (Select PartID from Part where DeleteDate is NOT NULL)`